# Moving Files and Folders using batch

Tags: batch-file

I want to move few files and folder available under a source folder to a destination Folder.
I am using :
move /y "%src%\" "%dest%".

This command is just moving files from the source but not the folders.

I need your suggestions. thanks in advance, i will appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

the command move has no option to move recursively. So you can try to copy recursively with xcopy /s /y and after this delete recursively the source directory with del /s /q. Finally rd /s /q to delete the folders because del will only delete the files.

Comment: Thanks ..Now when  I am using del /s /q, it is deleting the source directory not the content of the source directory . What i want to do is, after successful transfer I want to delete the content of the source directory..

Answer (score 0):

In my computer, with using command "move /Y src dest", the command works. Windows doesn't support the "move" command if the source folder and destination folder are in different volume. You can have a try.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but when I am trying "move /Y src dest" it is permanently  moving src folder into dest. What I want to do is, I want to move content(Files and subfolders) of the SRC folder to move in DEST folder.

Comment: @PRAX Oh, I see. Then you can use this command "xcopy src dest /e". “/e” means that will copy all files and subfolders even subfolders are empty. If you don‘t want to copy empty subfolders, then you can use "/s". I hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks Tianjipeng. It is working accordingly, but the thing is, now I want to delete the content of SRC folder(FILES AND SUBFOLDER) and able to delete files only not the subfolders..
 I have used  xcopy /y %src% %dest% /e
 del /q/s/a-d  "%src%"

Comment: @PRAX  If you want to delete all files and subfolders, you can use command "del /q/s src   for /f "delims="%%a in ('dir /ad/b/s src') do (rd /q/s "%%a")"

Comment: oh, then you can use this:  del /q/s src    cd src   for /d %%a in (*) do (rd /q/s "%%a")